# calling a function in angular controller from google api present in view

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-api, google-places-api

i am using google places details api. So in my src attribute I put google api which has a callback named initMap
Here is the code

```
<div class="tab-pane active"  id="timeline">
 <p class="lead">Location</p>
 <hr>
 <div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-1"></div>
  <div class="col-md-8">
   <h2><a href="#"></a> 
    <span>location <b style="color:black;"> kolkata</b></span></h2>
      <p></p>
      <div id="map" style="width:100%;height:400px;"></div>
      <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=API_KEY&libraries=places&callback=initMap"></script>
     <p></p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

In same html I have written initMap function

```
<script>
function initMap() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      center: {lat: 22.652687, lng: 88.376882},
      zoom: 15
    });

    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
    var service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);

    service.getDetails({
      placeId: 'ChIJvYbRT7Gd-DkR6QZQfJP9ZJg'
    }, function(place, status) {
      debugger
      if (status === google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          map: map,
          position: place.geometry.location
        });
        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
          infowindow.setContent('<div><strong>' + place.name + '</strong><br>' +
            'Place ID: ' + place.place_id + '<br>' +
            place.formatted_address + '</div>');
          infowindow.open(map, this);
        });
      }
    });
}
</script>
```

This works perfectly as long as this function is present inside script tag. 
How do I call initMap inside controller?

Answer (score 1):

You can't call it that way but instead you will load the script using javascript inside your controller when your app is loaded using `document.createElement('script')` then hook up a `onload` event listener then append it inside `head` head tag.

most likely:

```
var script = document.createElement('script');
script.src = 'google api script';
script.onload = function () {
// your onload function
$scope.onload();
$scope.$digest();
};

document.querySelector('head').appendChild(script);
```

this way you have control over what ng stuff you want to do everytime it loads. hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

When inside your HTML page, you create a function, the function will be automatically assigned to the `window` object, because that's the default scope of the scripts included in the page.

So from your controller, you should be able to simply call the function just using: `window.initMap();`